# Combine two fusion table sample not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am new to fusion table and Google Maps.
I try to combine this two sample into one

[sample1](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow/tabs.html)

[sample2](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query)

But I can't make both function work on the same times.
the info windows with tabs work fine
but if i select drop down list and click button "maps it"
nothing happen, it should update accordingly.

Appreciate any one can help me finds out what wrong with it,
I has suffer with this few days already. Thank you

my final code
[click me](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B5dnb9JhVY-8WnZxTmc0Y2Eza3c)

Comment: sample 1 link
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow/tabs.html

new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks on above, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put [your code on jsFiddle and made some corrections](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/Um2ag/).

- You added the Google Maps library twice, that doesn't work
- The layer was a local variable not accessible by the `refreshFusion()` function
- The generated where clause was erroneous, I changed it to use column names without quotes, the equal sign (`=`) instead of `CONTAINS` and finally changed it to the new syntax with `setOptions()`

Comment: Dear Odi,

Thank you so much, you save my day.
One more question, how to dynamically update the query with without to press the button "maps it"?

Comment: You can use the `onchange` event handler of the `<select>` items and add the`refreshFusion()` function. Just like you used the `onclick` event handler on the button. I updated my example with this change: http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/Um2ag/